# Opening up my side drawer causes a header with fixed position to move when the page is scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/genbxukk/1/)

I have two `div` elements in the `body`, `#drawer` and `#content`.  Inside the div `#content` is a `header` which is `position: fixed`.

When the top left menu button in the header is clicked, the main `#content` div is translated using css3 transforms and a transition to simulate an "opened" state for the drawer. It's when I do this that the problem occurs.

Scrolling the `#content` div while the `#drawer` is open, or scrolling this div a little and then opening the `#drawer` causes the `header` to move up to the top of the page, even though it's fixed.

Not precisely sure what the problem is after a little while staring at it, would love a few more experienced eyes on it as I'm trying to get it done as quickly as possible.

Would really appreciate any help you guys can offer me. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think do get what you want you would have to stick `header` outside of `#content` so it becomes fixed to the window and not `#content`. See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/genbxukk/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had problems when using *transform* and *position:fixed* together. In my **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lb5kjcp/1/)** I used *transition* instead of *transform*. I also modified your jQuery just a touch, but I think you'll get the idea.

The key is this:

```
#content.open,
#content.open header{
    left: 70%;
}
#content, header {
    transition: 300ms left;
    -webkit-transition: 300ms left;
    -moz-transition: 300ms left;
    -o-transition: 300ms left;
    left: 0;
}
```